# How can I make this animated div returning in one button?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

```
<script>
$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+100px"}, "slow").fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
});

$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+50px"}, "slow").fadeTo("slow", 0.99);;
});
</script>
```

this is my script.
as you see, i want to move  .block to left and right using button, but i can't find how to make it work in one button.

so i want the button to trigger  .block to move right (at the first click) and after it moves, trigger  .block to move left(second click). and can work repeatedly.

how can i do that?
should i use 'if' function?

Comment: there is ;; at the end of left click..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jFuQD/2/)

```
$("#right").click(function () {
   if (!$(".block").hasClass("Moved")) {
       $(".block").animate({
           "left": "+100px"
       }, "slow").fadeTo("slow", 0.33).addClass("Moved");
   } else {
       $(".block").animate({
           "left": "+50px"
       }, "slow").fadeTo("slow", 0.99).removeClass("Moved");
   }
});
```

Another Option:

Use a small plugin like this;

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function() {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

And use it like anywhere in your page:

```
$("#right").clickToggle(function () {
    $(".block").animate({
        "left": "+100px"
    }, "slow").fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
}, function () {
    $(".block").animate({
        "left": "+50px"
    }, "slow").fadeTo("slow", 0.99);;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".left").toggle(function(){
    $(".block").animate({"left": "+100px"}, "slow").fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
}, function(){
    $(".block").animate({"left": "+50px"}, "slow").fadeTo("slow", 0.99);
});
```

you can read more about .toggle() here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: The `.toggle()` that you're using has been removed from jQuery 1.9

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is as below.

```
$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+100px"}, "slow").fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
});

$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+50px"}, "slow").fadeTo("slow", 0.99);;
});
```

everytime you click on left or right you are increasing left property that means there is no right moving animation code exists.

Also remove `;;` from left click event code.

Try

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>StackOverFlow</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $("#right").click(function(){
                 $(".block").animate({
                    left: "100px"
                }, 1500 );
            });

            $("#left").click(function(){
                $(".block").animate({
                    left: "0"
                }, 1500 );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<button id="left" type="button">Left</button>
<button id="right" type="button">Right</button>
</div>

<div class="block" style="border:1px solid red;width:100px;height:100px;position: absolute;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this qhat you were looking for?

HTML:

```
<div class="block"></div>
<button type="button" id="move">Move</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#move").click(function () {
    $(".block").animate({
        left: "+100px"
    }, "slow")
        .animate({
        opacity: 0.33
    }, "slow")
        .animate({
        left: "+50px"
    }, "slow")
        .animate({
        opacity: 0.99
    }, "slow");
});
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#move {
    margin-top: 150px
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7xZXV/1/)

Comment: thanks, but this effect is not the one i try to find...
but thank you anyway!